# jQuery datepicker on dynamically generated rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I am dynamically generating table rows using the following javascript codes:

```
$('#addNew').on('click', function() {
    var clone = $('table.table-responsive tr.cloneme:first').clone();
    console.log(clone);
    clone.append("<td><button class='deleteAdded btn btn-danger'>Remove</button></td>")
    $('table.table-responsive').append(clone);
    calculateSum();
});
```

And this is my script for appending jQuery calendar to date inputs

```
$(function() {
    $('input').filter('.datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
    });
});
```

Now the problem I am facing is that the jQuery calendar pops up only in the first row. It doesn't work on the rows that are generated.

This in my html

```
<td>
    <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" name="invoiceDate[]" readonly="readonly" />
</td>
```

Please tell me how to make jQuery calendar work on all the rows that are dynamically generated. Looked around Google but nothing helped.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: add datepicker code after  calculateSum();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initiate the datepicker after the new rows are created

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  //create a original copy of the row to clone later
  var $tr = $('table.table-responsive tr.cloneme:first').clone();

  //add dp to existing rows
  addDP($('input.datepicker'));

  $('#addNew').on('click', function() {
    var clone = $tr.clone();
    console.log(clone);
    clone.append("<td><button class='deleteAdded btn btn-danger'>Remove</button></td>");
    //add dp to the new row
    addDP(clone.find('input.datepicker'));
    $('table.table-responsive').append(clone);
    calculateSum();
  });

  function addDP($els) {
    $els.datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<table class="table-responsive">
  <tr class="cloneme">
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" name="invoiceDate[]" readonly="readonly" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="addNew">Add</button>
```

Comment: Thank you. Your code helped a lot and it worked for me. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#addNew').on('click',function(){
    .....
    .....
    addDP();
});

addDP();

function addDP(){

    $('input').filter('.datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
    });

}
```